# "Audio device got stuck!" with bluetooth after one minute

Tags: 14.04, sound, bluetooth

On ubuntu 14.04 I have been connected to an audio device via bluetooth (bluetooth manager; audio sink). The audio plays on the external bluetooth device when I start an audio file with `mplayer`, but after 30 to 60 seconds, without doing something, I get the message

```
Audio device got stuck!
```

and there is no more audio on the bluetooth device. Even restarting the bluetooth service with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```

does not help - not even the bluetooth manager will restart. The only help is to restart the laptop, connect again with bluetooth only to lose connection again after 30-60 seconds...

How to find out what is going on?

Comment: For me it happens when my headset is connected to two devices (e.g., computer + smartphone) and when a sound is played on the smartphone. The solution proposed works but to avoid triggering this you can disconnect from the smartphone.

Answer (score 5):

I meet the same problem. And I'm convinced that it is a bug triggered inadvertently. I solved it through restarting pulseaudio daemon:

`$ pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start`

Sound come back.

Comment: This is annoying and should not happen. I'm having a similar problem, and I disconnec the device and re-connect. Has this been reported on launchpad somewhere?

Comment: @IvanPerez    it might not be. You can file a bug on launchpad to help them to improve